# How to do a Lookup of Data from a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, lookup

How do I achieve this in Python. I know there is a vlookup function in excel but if there is a way in Python, I prefer to do it in Python. Basically my goal is to get data from CSV2 column Quantity and write the data to column Quantity of CSV1 based on Bin_Name. The script should not copy all the value at once, it must be by selecting a Bin_Name. Ex: For today, I would like to get the data from Bin_Name ABCDE of CSV2 to CSV1 then it will write the data in column Quantity of CSV1. If this is possible, I will be very grateful and will learn a lot from this. Thank you very much in advance.

```
CSV1                     CSV2

Bin_Name   Quantity      Bin_Name   Quantity
A                        A          43  
B                        B          32
C                        C          28
D                        D          33 
E                        E          37   
F                        F          38
G                        G          39
H                        H          41
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply iterate CSV2 first, then after gathering wanted value, you can search it in CSV1. I wrote a code below it might help you, but there can be much more efficient ways to do.

```py
def func(wanted_rows: list,csv2df: pd.DataFrame):
    # Iterate csv2df
    for index,row in csv2df.iterrows():
        # Check if index in the wanted list
        if index in wanted_rows:
            # Get index of CSV1 for same value
            csv1_index = CSV1[CSV1.Bin_Name == row['Bin_Name']].index[0]
            CSV1.at[csv1_index,'Quantity'] = row['Quantity']
    return df

wanted_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
func(wanted_list,CSV2df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @VolkanM, I will give it a try and let you know. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner in Python and I think you shared is also complete? :) How do I correct this Sir? IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 2

Comment: It means you have added extra tab under for or if statements. I have edit my first comment maybe it can help you to solve your problem

Comment: File "C:\LookupQty.py", line 13
    return df
    ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use pandas *built-in* functions in this case and there is no need for loops.

So, assuming that there is no duplicate bin names, try the code below to copy the whole column :

```
df1= pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2= pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

df1["Quantity"]= df2["Quantity"].where(df1["Bin_Name"].eq(df2["Bin_Name"]))

print(df1)

  Bin_Name  Quantity
0        A        43
1        B        32
2        C        28
3        D        33
4        E        37
5        F        38
6        G        39
7        H        41
```

If you need to copy only a subset of rows, use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
​
vals= ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
df1.loc[df1["Bin_Name"].isin(vals), "Quantity"] = df2.loc[df1["Bin_Name"].isin(vals), "Quantity"]
print(df1)

  Bin_Name  Quantity
0        A      43.0
1        B      32.0
2        C      28.0
3        D      33.0
4        E       NaN
5        F       NaN
6        G       NaN
7        H       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @abokey, I will give it a try and let you know. Appreciate your help!

Comment: How do I start with the whole code, I feel like these are incomplete? Sorry I'm just a beginner hehehehe but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hello @abokey, need your help here please Sir :) Thank you

Comment: To implement the code, you just need to replace `"file1.csv"` and `"file2.csv"` by the acutal paths/names of your `.csv` files.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did change the path of the file but I got this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LookupQty.py", line 7, in <module>
    df1["Quantity"]= df2["Quantity"].where(df1["Bin_Name"].eq(df2["Bin_Name"]))
  File "C:\frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Quantity'

Comment: in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Quantity'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: Can you `print(df1.columns)` and `print(df2.columns)` ?

Comment: Index(['Bin_Name', 'Name', 'Quantity', 'Date', 'Remarks', 'Unnamed: 5',
       'Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8', 'Unnamed: 9', 'Unnamed: 10',
       'Taka'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['Bin_Name', 'Quantity'], dtype='object')

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I followed your first script which is below: import pandas as pd

df1= pd.read_csv("C:/CSV1.csv")
df2= pd.read_csv("C:/CSV2.csv")

df1["Quantity"]= df2["Quantity"].where(df1["Bin_Name"].eq(df2["Bin_Name"]))

print(df1.columns)
print(df2.columns)

Comment: With that script, no error but it did nothing. :)

Comment: Do you need `CSV2.csv` to be overwritten in you local disk ? If so, add this line at the end `df1.to_csv("C:/CSV1.csv", index=False)`

Comment: Yes I need CSV1.csv to be overwritten on whatever data CSV2 have (Quantity per Bin_Name). However when I added this line, nothing happened but there is no error. hehehe Sorry

Comment: import pandas as pd

df1= pd.read_csv("C:/CSV1.csv")
df2= pd.read_csv("C:/CSV2.csv")

df1["Quantity"]= df2["Quantity"].where(df1["Bin_Name"].eq(df2["Bin_Name"]))
df1.to_csv("C:/CSV1.csv", index=False)

print(df1.columns)
print(df2.columns)

Comment: Hi @abokey, any thoughts please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I understood your question fully, but let me know if this answers your challenge.

The normally way of doing Excel-type operations in Python is by using the framework [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html). Using this, you can read, manipulate and save your CSV-files (and many other formats) using Python code.

### Setting up the example

EDIT: Ensure you have installed pandas by e.g. typing the following in your terminal: `pip install pandas`

Since I don't have your CSV-files, I will create them using Pandas, rather than using the built-in [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)-method.

```py
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "Bin_Name": ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"],
    "Quantity": []
}, orient="index").T

csv2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "Bin_Name": ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"],
    "Quantity": [43, 32, 28, 33, 37, 38, 39, 41]
}, orient="index").T
```

The way I understood your question, you want to specify which bins should be copied from your `csv1`-file to your `csv2`-file. In your example, you mention something like this:

```py
# Specify bins you want to copy
bins_to_copy = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Now, there are several ways of doing the copying-operation you mentioned. Some better than others. Since you explicitly say *"the script should not copy all the value at once"*, I will give one suggestions that follows you instructions, and one that I believe is a better approach.

### Solution 1 (bad - using for-loops)

```py
# Loop through each bin and copy cell value from csv2 to csv1
for bin_to_copy in bins_to_copy:
    csv1.loc[csv1["Bin_Name"]==bin_to_copy, "Quantity"] = csv2.loc[csv2["Bin_Name"]==bin_to_copy, "Quantity"]

# OUTPUT:
> csv1
  Bin_Name Quantity
0        A       43
1        B       32
2        C       28
3        D       33
4        E       37
5        F     None
6        G     None
7        H     None
```

This approach does exactly what I believe you are asking for. However, there are several weaknesses with it:

1. Looping through rows is a very slow approach compared to using more efficient, built-in methods provided in the Pandas-library
2. The approach is vulnerable to situations where you have duplicate bins in either of the CSV-files
3. The approach is vulnerable to situations where a bin only exists in one of the CSV-files
4. Since we have updated one cell at a time, Pandas doesn't understand that the datatype of the column has changed, and we are still left with `None` for the missing values (and an "object"-type for the column) rather than `NaN` (which would indicate a numeric (float) column datatype).

If I have understood your problem correctly, then a better approach would be as follows

### Solution 2 (better - using merge)

```py
# Select the columns with bins from csv1
csv1_bins = csv1["Bin_Name"]

# Select only the rows with the desired bins from csv2
csv2_desired_bins = csv2[csv2["Bin_Name"].isin(bins_to_copy)]

# Merge the columns (just "Quantity" in this case) from csv2 to csv1 using "Bin_Name" as "merging-key"
result = pd.merge(left=csv1_bins, right=csv2_desired_bins, on="Bin_Name", how="left")

# OUTPUT
> result
  Bin_Name Quantity
0        A       43
1        B       32
2        C       28
3        D       33
4        E       37
5        F      NaN
6        G      NaN
7        H      NaN
```

The [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)-method is much more powerful and answers all the challenges I listed solution 1. It is also a more generic version of the [join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)-method, which according to the documentation is *"like an Excel VLOOKUP operation."* (which is what you mention would be you Excel equivalent)

Comment: Thank you for your response @ViggoTW, I will give it a try and let you know. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Your options i'm sure are great but I'm trying to recreate it but I keep getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\LookupQty.py", line 46, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: Also, there will be random data on BIN_NAME and Quantity so it's not always ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"] and numbers. And I apologize if I need the whole script since I am a beginner on this. Thank you very much for the assist.

Comment: I recommend trying to google the error messages you receive, as I see you have posted several trivial error messages in other replies. I do not have enough stack-credit to reply to other comments, but the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'" error means you have not installed pandas. You need to run "pip install pandas" in your terminal first.